# VB.NET file for compilation of CLS to DLL

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have a vb 6.0 file that compiles a CLS file in the same folder to a dll without the creation of any windows forms.  Does anyone know of an example for this in VB.NET?

Comment: Are you talking about creating a `Class Library`?

Comment: I don't think so.  I'm trying to create an extension for Aspen HYSYS and I need to keep updating and compiling a CLS to a dll to test it in HYSYS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Implementing a Class Library in VB.NET](http://www.csunit.org/tutorials/tutorial6/)

and specifically at **Create the class library project**

or [Implementing Class Library Object in VB.NET 2005](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/vb.net-2005/implementing-class-library-object-in-vb.net-2005.html)

or [Building a Class Library Component and Consumer Client Application with VB.NET](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/BuildingClassLibrary04262005091233AM/BuildingClassLibrary.aspx)